# Can I use the onclick scrollBy event on an iframe within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've been trying to solve this issue for a few days now and its driving me crazy. I
m not even sure if it is possible, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I have searched through hundreds of answers on this great website and I can not find the one I am looking for.

I am trying to use a button to scroll the content of an iframe on my html page.

Basically I have two iframes (named iframe1 & iframe2) they sit side by side on my html page. I have 2 buttons underneath each iframe. iframe1 is to scroll up and down and so the buttons are named "Up & Down" they work fine using the following code:

```
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="frame1.scrollBy(0,-200)"  value="Up" /> 
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="frame1.scrollBy(0, +200)"  value="Down" />
```

The second iframe (iframe2) holds an html page (named card.html) that has 2 more iframes in it (this is where it gets confusing) the 2 new iframes are called iframe3 & iframe4. I only want to scroll iframe4.

How can I cause it to scroll, I have tried applying the same functionality I used for iframe1 but for some reason it does not work.

i.e.

```
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="frame4.scrollBy(0,-200)"  value="Up" />
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="frame4.scrollBy(0,-200)"  value="Up" />
```

I guess it has something to do with the fact that the iframe is inside another iframe and the buttons are on the main html page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a (reasonably well-educated) guess, but try `frame2.frame4.scrollBy(0,-200)`. You need to get the iframe from inside of the other iframe before you can do stuff with it.